# Like/Dislike System using Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create two buttons, one for like, and the other for dislike.

I write this:

```
mDatabaseLikeReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (clickLike) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {

     mDatabaseRateMinsReference.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();

                    clickLike= false;
                } else {
                    mDatabaseRateMinsReference.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName());

                    clickLike= false;
                }


            } } @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
```

This is work for one button, how do if user click on like button, then dislike button, the like removed from database and vice versa? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

implement `onClickListener` for your button and in `onClick(View view)` do this:

```
// based on what button clicked, you can also check if button is enabled.
if(view.getid()== R.id.unlikeButton){
    mDatabaseLikeReference.removeValue();
}
else if (view.getid()== R.id.likedButton)
    mDatabaseLikeReference.setValue(mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName());
```

then in your database value event listener:

```
mDatabaseLikeReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                mDatabaseRateMinsReference
                    .child(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                    .setValue(mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName());
                    likedbutton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    unlikebutton.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
            else{
                 mDatabaseRateMinsReference
                     .child(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                     .removeValue();
                    // enable/disable or change visibility or change color
                    likedbutton.setVisibility(GONE);
                    unlikebutton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    } 

                 } @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
```

Comment: Not working , and also like what I said there two button . Thank u.

Comment: The function I want like youtube button like and other dislike

Comment: please see the changes in the edit, it will work now on two buttons