# How do I make it so it does not just like the newest post and it will like the post that they clicked the like button on?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I make it so it does not just like the newest post and it will like the post that they clicked the like button on?

code:

```
postSearch.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
  async function findPosts() {
    const postsRef = collection(firestore, "posts")
    const q = query(postsRef, orderBy("createdAt"));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((post) => {

      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      if (post.data().likes == undefined) {
        post.data().likes = 0
      }

      function epicTest() {
        let postData = {
          description: post.data().description,
          display_name: post.data().display_name,
          createdAt: post.data().createdAt,
          uid: post.data().uid,
          title: post.data().title,
          likes: post.data().likes + 1
        }
        console.log(post.id)
        console.log(postData)
        setDoc(doc(postsRef, post.id), postData)
        console.log("this feature hasn't been added yet")
      }
      let items = querySnapshot.docs.map(post => {
        if (post.data().title.includes(ev.target.value) || post.data().description.includes(ev.target.value)) {
          return `<div id="postBox">
      <h4 id="postName">${post.data().display_name}</h4>
      <h1 id="postTitle">${post.data().title}</h1>
      <h3 id="postDescription">${post.data().description}</h3>
      <div id="likeContainer"><ion-icon name="thumbs-up-outline" id="likeBtn" onclick="epicTest()"></ion-icon><h3 id="likeCount">${post.data().likes}</h3></div>
      </div>`

        }
      });
      items.reverse()
      postList.innerHTML = items.join('');
      if (postList.innerText == "") {
        postList.innerText = "no results found"
      }
      let likeBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#likeBtn")
      likeBtn.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
          let postData = {
            description: post.data().description,
            display_name: post.data().display_name,
            createdAt: post.data().createdAt,
            uid: post.data().uid,
            title: post.data().title,
            likes: post.data().likes + 1
          }
          console.log(post.id)
          console.log(postData)
          setDoc(doc(postsRef, post.id), postData)
          console.log("this feature hasn't been added yet")
        })
      })
    });
  }
  findPosts()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows how you can use the function to run whenever a 'Like' button is clicked, check the below sample:

```
    var postRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + id);
    postRef.child('like-count').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var currentLikes = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
        postRef.update({
            'postID': id,
            'like-count': currentLikes + 1
            }, function(error) {
              if (error) {
                console.log('Data could not be saved:' + error);
              } else {
                console.log('Data saved successfully');
              }
            });
        getLikeCount(id);
    });   
}
```

The basic idea behind this is to pass the post id as a parameter to the function that is called when clicking the like button.

Also check the following examples for similar implementations:

- [Like/Dislike function for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300034/like-dislike-function-for-firebase)
- [Creating like button using firestore and useeffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758558/creating-like-button-using-firestore-and-useeffect-usestate-is-causing-a-loop)
- [Like-Dislike system using Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946693/like-dislike-system-using-firebase-database)
- [How to implement like button concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320089/how-to-implement-like-button-concept-in-viewpager)
- [Like button functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720152/flutter-like-button-functionality-using-futures)

Comment: Is this for the firebase database or firebase firestore? I was using firestore for this just letting you know.

Comment: Yes, you may use this with the similar examples shared above for Firebase Database and with firestore queries.